# Client disconnect after 10bytes of data from server websocket

Tags: websocket

I managed to get past the handshake stage of the client server websocket connection but now i have a problem sending data from the server to the client. Here is the code that sends the data:

```
public void Send(String s)throws IOException{

os = socket.getOutputStream();

byte[] rawData = s.getBytes("UTF-8");

int frameCount  = 0;
byte[] frame = new byte[10];

frame[0] = (byte) 129;

if(rawData.length <= 125){
    frame[1] = (byte) rawData.length;
    frameCount = 2;
}else if(rawData.length >= 126 && rawData.length <= 65535){
    frame[1] = (byte) 126;
    byte len = (byte) rawData.length;
    frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
    frame[3] = (byte)(len & (byte)255); 
    frameCount = 4;
}else{
    frame[1] = (byte) 127;
    byte len = (byte) rawData.length;
    frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 56 ) & (byte)255);
    frame[3] = (byte)((len >> 48 ) & (byte)255);
    frame[4] = (byte)((len >> 40 ) & (byte)255);
    frame[5] = (byte)((len >> 32 ) & (byte)255);
    frame[6] = (byte)((len >> 24 ) & (byte)255);
    frame[7] = (byte)((len >> 16 ) & (byte)255);
    frame[8] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
    frame[9] = (byte)(len & (byte)255);
    frameCount = 10;
}

int bLength = frameCount + rawData.length;

byte[] reply = new byte[bLength];

int bLim = 0;
for(int i=0; i<frameCount;i++){
    reply[bLim] = frame[i];
    bLim++;
}
for(int i=0; i<rawData.length;i++){
    reply[bLim] = rawData[i];
    bLim++;
}
System.out.println(frame);
os.write(reply);
os.flush();
}
```

That is supposed to send the string s to the client.
I can send 9bytes of data but it is not received by the test client at echo websocket website, and if i send a tenth byte, the client disconnects saying "error:unknown".
Any idea what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!
Smollett.

Comment: What's the reason for the `& (byte)255` in the length fields? 255 has all bits set to 1, so AND-ing it with another 8-bit value returns that value.

Comment: The line `byte len = (byte) rawData.length;` will truncate the length to a byte. You are later bit-shifting it to get the value of the other length bytes. This will set them to 0. But that should only cause problems when sending more than 125 bytes.